# Making and displaying a video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-ndk, media

I have to develop an app which shoud crop and cut video .
I decide to use ffmpeg and I tested below library :

https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java


but I get `[libx264 @ 0xf506d400] using cpu capabilities: none!`at console  and running so so slowly.


so I decide to build my own ffmpeg prebuilt and try my hard and test below link for make prebuild ffmpeg :

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android
- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java
- http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android/
- http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/
  and so much more

But enety build has own error, such as "couldn't find c comiler"

After too many search I found and build ffmpeg but the result is some .so file (listed below):

- libavcodec-58.so
- libavdevice-58.so
- libavformat-58.so
- libavutil-56.so
- libpostproc-55.so
- libswresample-3.so
- libswscale-5.so

my build.sh is :

```
NDK=/Users/mehdi/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/ndk/android-ndk-r13b
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
function build_one
{
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --enable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --cpu=cortex-a8 \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-avfilter \
    --enable-encoders  \
    --enable-muxers \
    --enable-protocols  \
    --enable-parsers \
    --enable-demuxers \
    --enable-decoders \
    --enable-bsfs \
    --enable-network \
    --enable-swscale  \
    --enable-asm 

    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

and I put .so files into cpp folder in android studio and make CMakeLists.txt.
every thing is ok up to now but where can I found ffmpeg file to execute command in java .

Comment: @LordNeckbeard could you please answer me ?

Comment: You have `--disable-ffmpeg` so there won't be any ffmpeg binary built.

Comment: @Mulvya I did it but i get so small file which doesn't work !!!
almost 234 kb file !!!

Comment: @MehdiShojaeian Didn't get a notification–apparently using `@` to ping other users doesn't work unless the target is already in the discussion. The `using cpu capabilities: none!` message is coming from libx264, so you have to make sure you're not using `--disable-asm` for x264 as the WritingMinds script does. I'm not sure why it uses that option but I've never compiled for Android so maybe I'm missing the point.